# QSqlRelationalTableModel - two references to the same table, same foreign keys

Tags: c++, qt, qsqldatabase

I have 3 tables:

[image]

I would like to show the Orders table (order's start and end date, user's last name, service name and service price) on GUI using `QTableView` and `QSqlRelationalTableModel`.  Here's where I set up the table and the view:

```
this->ordersTable = new QTableView(this);
this->model = new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this, db->getDB());
this->model->setTable("ORDERS");
this->model->setRelation(3, QSqlRelation("USERS", "id", "lastname"));
this->model->setRelation(4, QSqlRelation("SERVICE", "id", "name"));
this->model->setRelation(4, QSqlRelation("SERVICE", "id", "price"));
this->model->select();
this->ordersTable->setModel(this->model);
this->ordersTable->hideColumn(0);
```

But when I do the third `setRelation` call, it seems, it overwrites the second call: I can only see the price on GUI, not both the name AND the price. And I need to put both fields - name and price from Services table to my view.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
this->model->setRelation(4, QSqlRelation("SERVICE", "id", "name, price"));
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems `setRelation` is used to resolve only one foreign key, but you want to add two columns. In this case you can use `QSqlQueryModel` to apply your own customized query.

```
QSqlQueryModel model;
QString q = "your sql query";
model.setQuery(q, db->getDB());
tableView->setModel(model);
```

For the query, you could achieve your goal with a simple inner join query.

```sql
SELECT O.ID, O.START_TIME, O.END_TIME, U.LASTNAME, S.NAME, S.PRICE
    FROM ORDERS O
        INNER JOIN USERS U
            ON O.USER_ID = U.ID
        INNER JOIN SERVICE S
            ON O.SERVICE_ID = S.ID
```

Comment: This could be the solution, however, I forgot to mention, that I need to make changes in DB, and the docs say that `The QSqlQueryModel class provides a read-only data model for SQL result sets`, so, I need something which won't be read-only. Thanks anyway :)